# why spring does not manages prototype bean once created

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

So regarding prototype scoped bean, I know spring just crate it do life cycle process before handover it to requested bean. and then if forgot it.And also logically I can understand that since it is prototype, it will be used by per request only (yes not http request.) But why not spring container just keep reference of prototype bean just to manage complete life cycle?

Comment: What are you trying to tell? Should spring itself keep a reference to one of the thousands or millions of prototype beans it has created ever since the application is running? Imagine a faactory that creates prototype beans. Imagine that factory creating many instances of these prototypes per http servlet request and many request per seconds. You would have an OutOfMemoryError in no time.

Answer (score 0):

A "prototype" scope behaves pretty much just like any object POJO created with the "new" operator, except for the Spring prototype will have @Autowired beans connected up. The aren't singletons, or connected to sesssion or request scope, so they are just more similar to a regular POJO.